# Filtering a tuple with a channel.collect in Nextflow

Tags: filter, tuples, nextflow

I've created a tuple from the output of a channel.

```
ch_groups = INPUT_CHECK_GEX.out.group_samplesheet
            .splitCsv( header:true, sep:',', strip:true )
            .map { row ->
                    def keyID = row["keyid"]
                    def sampleID = row["sampleid"]
                    return [keyID, sampleID]
                }
            .groupTuple()
        ch_groups.view()
```

This is the output

```
[group1-group2, [sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4]]
```

I have another output set up as a tuple as well: `SEURAT_SINGLE.out.rds.view()`

```
[sample3, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/b1/92baee56b862a2187f1459e1e66a4d/sample3_seurat_object.rds]
[sample7, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/37/6df9873421a81170aa8156c303bb3c/sample7_seurat_object.rds]
[sample6, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/7a/ebe2243cd6dbc81c2374be9e80c24b/sample6_seurat_object.rds]
[sample1, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/65/888f0fb28a20fe1c034e8da8666eee/sample1_seurat_object.rds]
[sample5, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/78/a0ce478d03da5fb4f67b34fcd194e4/sample5_seurat_object.rds]
[sample2, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/ec/98b2b1e045db5b0664233052e28e37/sample2_seurat_object.rds]
[sample4, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/44/5c38598986b3a48e05a4bcb5c72c73/sample4_seurat_object.rds]
```

I need to get a list of all the RDS files associated with each of the first outputs. For example, for `[group1-group2, [sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4]]` I need a list of :

```
/gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/65/888f0fb28a20fe1c034e8da8666eee/sample1_seurat_object.rds /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/ec/98b2b1e045db5b0664233052e28e37/sample2_seurat_object.rds/gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/b1/92baee56b862a2187f1459e1e66a4d/sample3_seurat_object.rds]
/gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/ec/98b2b1e045db5b0664233052e28e37/sample3_seurat_object.rds]
/gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/44/5c38598986b3a48e05a4bcb5c72c73/sample4_seurat_object.rds]
```

### EDITED with the advice from Steve

Using his approach I was able to get the desired result for one contrast. As soon as I added contrasts, the output still provided only the first result.

For example, adding additional contrasts to `INPUT_CHECK_GEX.out.group_samplesheet`:

```
ch_groups = INPUT_CHECK_GEX.out.group_samplesheet
            .splitCsv( header:true, sep:',', strip:true )
            .map { row ->
                    def keyID = row["keyid"]
                    def sampleID = row["sampleid"]
                    return [keyID, sampleID]
                }
            .groupTuple()
        ch_groups.view()

ch_groups.view()

[group1-group2, [sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4]]
[group1-group2-group3, [sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4, sample5, sample6]]
```

And then running his suggestion, still gives the output, ignoring the added contrast:

```
[group1-group2, [/gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/a6/02a8bc99a1a0ea3549d774145facbe/sample3_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/bf/2f9f884fe8868ee91ce077d598bd5d/sample4_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/1f/a18fc5718d3a7869da2340149254e3/sample2_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/8e/99e42901219cd3eba0981987033145/sample1_seurat_object.rds]]
```

I attempted to fix this with this solution, but while it brings in the second contrast, it doesn't map duplicate samples (IE sample1 is in BOTH contrasts):

```
INPUT_CHECK_GEX.out.group_samplesheet
            .splitCsv( header:true, sep:',', strip:true )
            .map { row ->
                def key = row["keyid"]
                def sample = row["sampleid"]

                tuple( key, sample )
            }
            .map { key, sample -> tuple( sample, key ) }
            .join( SEURAT_SINGLE.out.rds )
            .map { sample, key, rds_file -> tuple( key, rds_file ) }
            .groupTuple()
            .view()
```

Output:

```
[group1-group2-group3, [/gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/4c/747cbe34e3464a22c376d09be2cdb1/sample6_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/51/9bb8aad780fd14e9ed7ad9b3f3b06f/sample5_seurat_object.rds]
[group1-group2, [/gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/d8/b02c8c3ab57faefe4bb60e85b03743/sample3_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/27/eb43d9f44534819f289831869270a8/sample1_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/e2/2811ac1360970134456f34b7d55518/sample4_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/1f/a18fc5718d3a7869da2340149254e3/sample2_seurat_object.rds]]
```

Expected Output:

```
[group1-group2, [/gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/d8/b02c8c3ab57faefe4bb60e85b03743/sample3_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/27/eb43d9f44534819f289831869270a8/sample1_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/e2/2811ac1360970134456f34b7d55518/sample4_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/1f/a18fc5718d3a7869da2340149254e3/sample2_seurat_object.rds]]

[group1-group2-group3, [/gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/4c/747cbe34e3464a22c376d09be2cdb1/sample6_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/51/9bb8aad780fd14e9ed7ad9b3f3b06f/sample5_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/d8/b02c8c3ab57faefe4bb60e85b03743/sample3_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/27/eb43d9f44534819f289831869270a8/sample1_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/e2/2811ac1360970134456f34b7d55518/sample4_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/1f/a18fc5718d3a7869da2340149254e3/sample2_seurat_object.rds]
```

## Solution

For anyone else who finds themselves with this question, this was the solution I came up with:

```
        ch_groups = INPUT_CHECK_GEX.out.group_samplesheet
            .splitCsv( header:true, sep:',', strip:true )
            .map { row ->
                    def key = row["keyid"]
                    def sample = row["sampleid"]
                    return [sample, key]
                }
            .combine(SEURAT_SINGLE.out.rds, by: 0)
            .map { sample, key, rds_file -> tuple( key, rds_file ) }
            .groupTuple()
            .view()
```

Gives the output:

```
[group1-group2, [/gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/1f/a18fc5718d3a7869da2340149254e3/sample2_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/a6/02a8bc99a1a0ea3549d774145facbe/sample3_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/78/e7d26a4328f99d5984cdb1acd8e4b0/sample1_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/da/ca761f3d5b389f1333736ec5ae1dfe/sample4_seurat_object.rds]]

[group1-group2-group3, [/gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/1f/a18fc5718d3a7869da2340149254e3/sample2_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/a6/02a8bc99a1a0ea3549d774145facbe/sample3_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/98/1063e9c6b025e59238d84db688ece5/sample5_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/ec/c1924829b9e4298540c530aa37e919/sample6_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/78/e7d26a4328f99d5984cdb1acd8e4b0/sample1_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/da/ca761f3d5b389f1333736ec5ae1dfe/sample4_seurat_object.rds]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your group samplesheet contains multiple groups each with a different number of samples, you could use a [`groupKey`](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/blob/v23.04.1/modules/nextflow/src/main/groovy/nextflow/extension/GroupKey.groovy) object to associate the number of samples with each group. This approach lets the [`groupTuple`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#grouptuple) operator then stream the collected values as soon as possible. For example:

```
workflow {

    INPUT_CHECK_GEX.out.group_samplesheet
        .splitCsv( header:true, sep:',', strip:true )
        .map { row ->
            def keyID = row["keyid"]
            def sampleID = row["sampleid"]

            tuple( keyID, sampleID )
        }
        .groupTuple()
        .map { group, samples ->
            tuple( groupKey(group, samples.size()), samples )
        }
        .set { groups_ch }

    groups_ch
        .transpose()
        .map { key, sample -> tuple( sample, key ) }
        .join( SEURAT_SINGLE.out.rds )
        .map { sample, key, rds_file -> tuple( key, rds_file ) }
        .groupTuple()
        .view()
}
```

Expected results:

```
[group1-group2, [/gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/65/888f0fb28a20fe1c034e8da8666eee/sample1_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/ec/98b2b1e045db5b0664233052e28e37/sample2_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/b1/92baee56b862a2187f1459e1e66a4d/sample3_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/44/5c38598986b3a48e05a4bcb5c72c73/sample4_seurat_object.rds]]
```

---

Note that if a sample can belong to one or more groups, simply replace the [`join`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#join) with the [`combine`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#combine) operator. Just make sure to use the second form which allows you to combine items that share a common matching key using the `by` parameter, for example:

```
    groups_ch
        .transpose()
        .map { key, sample -> tuple( sample, key ) }
        .combine( SEURAT_SINGLE.out.rds, by: 0 )
        .map { sample, key, rds_file -> tuple( key, rds_file ) }
        .groupTuple()
        .view()
```

Expected results:

```
[group1-group2, [/gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/65/888f0fb28a20fe1c034e8da8666eee/sample1_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/ec/98b2b1e045db5b0664233052e28e37/sample2_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/b1/92baee56b862a2187f1459e1e66a4d/sample3_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/44/5c38598986b3a48e05a4bcb5c72c73/sample4_seurat_object.rds]]
[group1-group2-group3, [/gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/65/888f0fb28a20fe1c034e8da8666eee/sample1_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/ec/98b2b1e045db5b0664233052e28e37/sample2_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/b1/92baee56b862a2187f1459e1e66a4d/sample3_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/44/5c38598986b3a48e05a4bcb5c72c73/sample4_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/78/a0ce478d03da5fb4f67b34fcd194e4/sample5_seurat_object.rds, /gpfs/gsfs10/users/CCBR_Pipeliner/Pipelines/TechDev_scRNASeq_Dev2023/work/7a/ebe2243cd6dbc81c2374be9e80c24b/sample6_seurat_object.rds]]
```

Comment: I wish I could hug you - this is exactly what I needed for this example! When I expand the example though, the results are not as expected. See edit above.

Comment: @SamanthaSevilla No worries at all! I think we can just replace the `join` with a `combine`. Please see my edit above, thanks!